# Azure Functions does not run on Azure but works locally

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-standard-2.0

I am working on Azure Function App and i am using .net standard 2.0. Everything works fine locally. but when i publish the function app to azure, i am getting the Object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

Please check the screenshot below.

[image]

Can anyone help me sort out this issue. I have tried deleting the app and creating it again and restarted multiple times but nothing seems to work.

Thanks
Syed.

**UPDATE 1**

Please check the following screenshot that i received from the diagnostic logs.
[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Logs from KUDU.

```
2018-11-21T06:15:20.268 [Information] Host Status: {
  "id": "esaldafaterfunctions-dev",
  "state": "Running",
  "version": "2.0.12180.0",
  "versionDetails": "2.0.12180.0 Commit hash: a375d112383fb48f5acd0424bb807513a8917f6b"
}
2018-11-21T06:15:30.126 [Information] Host Status: {
  "id": "esaldafaterfunctions-dev",
  "state": "Running",
  "version": "2.0.12180.0",
  "versionDetails": "2.0.12180.0 Commit hash: a375d112383fb48f5acd0424bb807513a8917f6b"
}
2018-11-21T06:15:39.512 [Information] Host Status: {
  "id": "esaldafaterfunctions-dev",
  "state": "Running",
  "version": "2.0.12180.0",
  "versionDetails": "2.0.12180.0 Commit hash: a375d112383fb48f5acd0424bb807513a8917f6b"
}
2018-11-21T06:15:43.021 [Information] Stopping JobHost
2018-11-21T06:15:43.055 [Information] Job host stopped
2018-11-21T06:15:58.165 [Information] Initializing Host.
2018-11-21T06:15:58.175 [Information] Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1
2018-11-21T06:15:58.206 [Information] Starting JobHost
2018-11-21T06:15:58.214 [Information] Starting Host (HostId=esaldafaterfunctions-dev, InstanceId=d73e44cb-bbb3-4749-ac67-354729119e0c, Version=2.0.12180.0, ProcessId=6276, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=True, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=~2)
2018-11-21T06:15:58.244 [Information] Loading functions metadata
2018-11-21T06:15:58.305 [Information] 6 functions loaded
2018-11-21T06:15:58.375 [Information] Generating 0 job function(s)
2018-11-21T06:15:58.611 [Warning] Function 'Run' is async but does not return a Task. Your function may not run correctly.
2018-11-21T06:15:58.659 [Warning] Function 'Run' is async but does not return a Task. Your function may not run correctly.
2018-11-21T06:15:58.669 [Warning] Function 'Run' is async but does not return a Task. Your function may not run correctly.
2018-11-21T06:15:58.679 [Information] Found the following functions:
Esal.Dafater.DafaterInvoiceProcessor.Run
Esal.Dafater.DafaterPaymentProcessor.Run
Esal.Dafater.DafaterPaymentUpdater.Run
Esal.Dafater.EsalDocsTransferer.Run
Esal.Dafater.EsalPaymentProcessor.Run
Esal.Dafater.EsalReportProcessor.Run
2018-11-21T06:15:58.680 [Information] Host initialized (465ms)
2018-11-21T06:15:58.954 [Information] The next 5 occurrences of the 'Esal.Dafater.EsalReportProcessor.Run' schedule will be:
11/21/2018 6:20:00 AM
11/21/2018 6:25:00 AM
11/21/2018 6:30:00 AM
11/21/2018 6:35:00 AM
11/21/2018 6:40:00 AM
2018-11-21T06:15:58.954 [Information] The next 5 occurrences of the 'Esal.Dafater.DafaterPaymentProcessor.Run' schedule will be:
11/21/2018 6:20:00 AM
11/21/2018 6:25:00 AM
11/21/2018 6:30:00 AM
11/21/2018 6:35:00 AM
11/21/2018 6:40:00 AM
2018-11-21T06:15:58.955 [Information] Host started (740ms)
2018-11-21T06:15:58.955 [Information] Job host started
2018-11-21T06:15:58.962 [Error] The following 6 functions are in error:
DafaterInvoiceProcessor: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
DafaterPaymentProcessor: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
DafaterPaymentUpdater: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
EsalDocsTransferer: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
EsalPaymentProcessor: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
EsalReportProcessor: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2018-11-21T06:16:08.448 [Information] Initializing Host.
2018-11-21T06:16:08.458 [Information] Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1
2018-11-21T06:16:08.495 [Information] Starting JobHost
2018-11-21T06:16:08.497 [Information] Starting Host (HostId=esaldafaterfunctions-dev, InstanceId=572857ce-39a9-4eab-80f2-91bf79deb0a9, Version=2.0.12180.0, ProcessId=19092, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=True, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=~2)
2018-11-21T06:16:08.561 [Information] Loading functions metadata
2018-11-21T06:16:08.597 [Information] 6 functions loaded
2018-11-21T06:16:08.689 [Information] Generating 0 job function(s)
2018-11-21T06:16:08.808 [Warning] Function 'Run' is async but does not return a Task. Your function may not run correctly.
2018-11-21T06:16:08.868 [Warning] Function 'Run' is async but does not return a Task. Your function may not run correctly.
2018-11-21T06:16:08.896 [Warning] Function 'Run' is async but does not return a Task. Your function may not run correctly.
2018-11-21T06:16:08.899 [Information] Found the following functions:
Esal.Dafater.DafaterInvoiceProcessor.Run
Esal.Dafater.DafaterPaymentProcessor.Run
Esal.Dafater.DafaterPaymentUpdater.Run
Esal.Dafater.EsalDocsTransferer.Run
Esal.Dafater.EsalPaymentProcessor.Run
Esal.Dafater.EsalReportProcessor.Run
2018-11-21T06:16:08.899 [Information] Host initialized (395ms)
2018-11-21T06:16:09.049 [Information] The next 5 occurrences of the 'Esal.Dafater.EsalReportProcessor.Run' schedule will be:
11/21/2018 6:20:00 AM
11/21/2018 6:25:00 AM
11/21/2018 6:30:00 AM
11/21/2018 6:35:00 AM
11/21/2018 6:40:00 AM
2018-11-21T06:16:09.052 [Information] The next 5 occurrences of the 'Esal.Dafater.DafaterPaymentProcessor.Run' schedule will be:
11/21/2018 6:20:00 AM
11/21/2018 6:25:00 AM
11/21/2018 6:30:00 AM
11/21/2018 6:35:00 AM
11/21/2018 6:40:00 AM
2018-11-21T06:16:09.052 [Information] Host started (548ms)
2018-11-21T06:16:09.052 [Information] Job host started
2018-11-21T06:16:09.058 [Error] The following 6 functions are in error:
DafaterInvoiceProcessor: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
DafaterPaymentProcessor: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
DafaterPaymentUpdater: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
EsalDocsTransferer: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
EsalPaymentProcessor: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
EsalReportProcessor: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2018-11-21T06:16:14.130 [Information] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '036afd797780213c0dd87264cf9c02c4'.
2018-11-21T06:16:35.006 [Information] Host Status: {
  "id": "esaldafaterfunctions-dev",
  "state": "Running",
  "version": "2.0.12180.0",
  "versionDetails": "2.0.12180.0 Commit hash: a375d112383fb48f5acd0424bb807513a8917f6b"
}
2018-11-21T06:16:57.533 [Information] Host Status: {
  "id": "esaldafaterfunctions-dev",
  "state": "Running",
  "version": "2.0.12180.0",
  "versionDetails": "2.0.12180.0 Commit hash: a375d112383fb48f5acd0424bb807513a8917f6b"
}
2018-11-21T06:18:10.164 [Information] Host Status: {
  "id": "esaldafaterfunctions-dev",
  "state": "Running",
  "version": "2.0.12180.0",
  "versionDetails": "2.0.12180.0 Commit hash: a375d112383fb48f5acd0424bb807513a8917f6b"
}
```

Comment: Do you get that exception on publish or on run?

Comment: Both built-in logging and Application Insights can be used to collect more information about the exception https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring

Comment: @Fildor publish is working fine, however it function app is never getting executed, these function apps were working fine a month ago but lately they are giving these errors for Object Reference. I have also attached an image from Diagnostics logs.

Comment: @LexLi i have attached the screenshot from Diagnostics logs.

Comment: @SyedAbdulQadeer Could you go to kudu `https://<functionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and navigate to `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host` for detailed logs.

Comment: @JerryLiu i have added the logs from Functions\Host.

Comment: @SyedAbdulQadeer See `Function 'Run' is async but does not return a Task`, try to remove async or return Task. Besides, could you verify whether there's an app setting `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` with value `dotnet` in Application settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Application Setting, in Azure Portal. The FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME was set to node, changing it to dotnet solved the issue.

THanks
Syed.